# Removing ViewController after performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I am making an iOS game application in Xcode and I perform a segue programmatically when a timer hits the end, as shown in the following code:

```
 let endGame = DispatchTime.now() + 10
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: endGame) {
        print("The game has ended")
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "timerSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

My problem is that when the segue is already performed and I'm in the next screen I can hear sounds that reveal that the previous screen is still up and running and I want a way to remove it or delete it completely since the app is never going back to that view.

Comment: Could you add the code for playing sound?

Comment: you can stop playing sound on viewWillDisappear

Comment: I have this inside a collisionBehaviour.action                                                          do{
                        self.kickSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: self.kickUrl!)
                        self.kickSoundEffect?.play()
                    }
                    catch{
                       print("Couldn't load audio file")
                    }